# how to get data from choice field of form from html to views in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

i am not able to fetch or get data from html post request to form
i want to give selection option to use to choose any single data and i want that data in my database
my html file

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>Gender</label>
  <form action="{% url 'my_view' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <select name="gender" class="selectpicker" data-title="Select Gender" data-style="btn-default btn-block" data-menu-style="dropdown-blue">
  {% for x,y in form.fields.gender.choices %}
     <option value="{{ x }}"{% if form.fields.gender.value == x %} selected{% endif %}>{{ y }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
  
</div>  
</div>
```

my forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kargs)

    class Meta:
         model = models.User
         fields = '__all__'
```

my models.py

```
gender = (
    ('x', 'filled'),
    ('y', 'notfilled'),
    )

class User(models.Model):
    lat = models.DecimalField(('Latitude'), max_digits=10, decimal_places=8,null=True)
    lng = models.DecimalField(('Longitude'), max_digits=11, decimal_places=8,null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, default='',choices=gender,verbose_name="gender")
```

answer me what to write in views.py please
my views.py

```
def bins(request):
    form = UserForm()
    return render(request ,'bins.html',{'form': form})

def my_view(request):
    form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
    answer = form.cleaned_data.get('gender') if form.is_valid() else ''
    return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all edit your User model gender choices name to UPPER-CASE:

```
GENDER = (
    ('x', 'filled'),
    ('y', 'notfilled'),
    )

class User(models.Model):
    lat = models.DecimalField(('Latitude'), max_digits=10, decimal_places=8,null=True)
    lng = models.DecimalField(('Longitude'), max_digits=11, decimal_places=8,null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, default='',choices=GENDER,verbose_name="gender")
```

edit your form and add "selectpicker"(your select input class) to gender field:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kargs)

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'gender': forms.Select(choices=models.User.GENDER, attrs={'class':'selectpicker'}),
         }
```

in your  template:

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>Gender</label>
  <form action="{% url 'my_view' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
  {{form.gender}}
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
  
</div>  
</div>
```